# How to navigate to previous fragment without reloading in navigation component architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have Fragment A which loads some data when it opens. It has one button when we click. It navigate to Fragment B. That's not the issue, the problem is when I press back Button in Fragment B it comes to Fragment A and reload that data in Fragment A. My problem is I don't want to reload that data in  Fragment A When back press From Fragment B.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have one flag in  companion object and check its value before reloading.

Comment: Can you eloborate or some code for that. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't reload the data? Are you replacing the fragment A with B and adding it to backstack?

Comment: I am replacing the fragment not backstack it.

Comment: <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_showPurchaseFragment"
            app:destination="@id/showPurchaseFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in_animation"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out_animation"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in_animation"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out_animation" />

Comment: This is my code. I am not back stacking Fragment B

Comment: Include your FragmentA code and how you 'load some data when it opens'.

Comment: Its just display a Toast message when fragment A opens that's it. But that toast show when i comes back to fragment A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Dharmender's approach but if you are not using viewmodel then you can try this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val tv1 = requireActivity().findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv1)
        tv1.setOnClickListener {
            if(!isUpdated) {
                isUpdated = true
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace((requireView().parent as ViewGroup).id, F2.newInstance())
                    .addToBackStack("f2").commit()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"Already updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.e(TAG,"On create view")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f1, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            F1()
        val TAG = F1::class.java.simpleName
        var isUpdated = false
    }
```

Here I am using one flag isUpdated.

Comment: Thanks man, for this solution it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You should use viewModel and put your all data inside viewModel, In case of back press fragment will reload but your data will not refresh it will same as previous was on view.

```
Class TestViewModel:ViewModel(){

 init{
   apiReqest()
 }

fun apiReqest(){
 // writer here your api request code and observe it on view using observer
} 

}
```